# How to remove space at the start of inline enumitem itemized list?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, enumitem

Here I show the out-of-the-box behaviour of an inline itemized list, and then a workaround that achieves the look I'm after.  The desired look is achieved, here, by manually adding a negative space to left-align the first line of the lede.  Can the alignment be made to work as desired using built in enumitem options?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{itemize*}[label=,leftmargin=*,]
\item In this Introduction we have recalled the \textbf{necessary
  background} on sonic screwdrivers, and presented \textbf{supporting
  material} to frame our research.
\end{itemize*}

\section{Re-introduction}

\begin{itemize*}[label=,leftmargin=*,]
\item \hspace{-.5em}In this Introduction we have recalled the
  \textbf{necessary background} on sonic screwdrivers, and presented
  \textbf{supporting material} to frame our research.
\end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what is the purpose then of doing this as a list?

Comment: see the `afterlabel` option, setting it to `afterlabel=,` aka no value seems to work. I still do not understand the use case though.

Comment: I started with a bullet list, and now just want to change how it looks.  I realise I could get the text to flow in the usual way if I remove the list markup, but it feels like enumitem should be able to take care of that for me.   That way I can preserve the logical structure.

Comment: thanks - if you put that as an answer I am happy to accept.

Comment: Most people use \section or \subsection for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For inline lists there are a few extra options. For example `afterlabel` by default inserts a non-breaking space (a same as `~`) after the list label. Since there are no label here, the non breaking space is clearly visible.

Using

```
afterlabel=,
```

sets this value to be empty, and the space goes away.